# What is the name for the 'describe it' format in testing?

Tags: ruby, rspec

This is with `ruby-rspec` but I have seen it for other languages too.
`BDD` is one term but maybe that is to too general as it covers `Cucumber` which doesn't use this format.

Example:

```
describe "Stuff" do
  it "does stuff" do
     a=1
     expect(a).to eq 1
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've generally seen it referred to as "xSpec"; that style was popularised, if not invented, by [RSpec](http://rspec.info/) and there are others like JSpec (for Java, which uses `it` but not `describe`).

The JavaScript framework Mocha (and other tools that have adopted it, like [Cypress](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/bundled-tools.html#Mocha)) refers to this API as "the [BDD](https://mochajs.org/#bdd) interface". [Jasmine](https://jasmine.github.io), which also uses that style but doesn't explicitly name it, describes itself as a *"behavior-driven development framework"*, and was explicitly influenced by RSpec and JSpec.

*(It's certainly not xUnit; xUnit test frameworks are those that represent suites as classes implementing TestCase and tests as methods on those classes.)*